# Can you scan Animal Crossing cards on a New 3DS without an NFC Reader and Writer?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, amiibo, animal-crossing-happy-home-designer

I am thinking about getting Animal Crossing: Happy Home Designer.

If you use a New 3DS, can you use the built-in amiibo NFC area for scanning cards or do you need the scanner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NFC Reader/Writer is just intended to be used with 3DS devices that don't have the built in ability to scan amiibo/ amiibo cards, like the New 3DS does.

If you have a New 3DS, you will not need this device as you can just use the built in capabilities of the New 3DS to scan the amiibo cards.

Comment: Isn't it only the XL version that has it built in? I'm sure on the official website it said that the normal doesn’t have support.

Comment: From NIntendo's press release for the standard sized New 3DS: "New Nintendo 3DS incorporates all the same enhanced features as the New Nintendo 3DS XL system, including a wider range of controls, face-tracking 3D and built-in NFC functionality that allows for communication with amiibo figures. " (So no, it's not just the N3DS XL, it's any N3DS.)